# php mySQL pdo auto_increment primary key for row

Tags: php, mysql

How do you set allow mySQL to auto increment a row in mySQL when using php?  I have set the link_id column as auto_increment using phpMyAdmin but I do not know how to get the row to auto increment when using PDO.

```
$preparedStatement = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO link (link_id, category, link_desc, link_url) VALUES (:link_id, :category, :link_desc, :link_url)');
$preparedStatement-> execute(array(':link_id' => **AUTO INCREMENT Field in mySQL**, ':category' => $category,':link_desc' => $link_desc,':link_url' => $link_url));
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything special with PHP, but there are several ways in MySQL.  One is to use a falsey value or null:

```
INSERT INTO link (<columns>) VALUES (null, category...
```

Just exclude the parameter in PHP.

You can also specify columns to insert, and if you leave off the auto_increment key, it gets auto incremented:

```
INSERT INTO link (category, link_desc...)
```

Comment: Does specifying `null` in an auto_increment field have a defined behavior? I prefer to just leave it out of the query. Oh never mind it, just found that `NULL` and `0` are also valid according to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Is this a PDO solution?? It doesn't look like it to me, I am having the same trouble. Where mysql automatically inserts an auto increment, it seems PDO does not. Do you have a solution,please?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column at INSERT statement with any value ... 
MySQL automatically will override `AUTO_INCREMENT` column value that are defined into your statement and handle with new value correctly.

In console mode it generates a warning if the value wasn't set correctly, but in PHP i think it will be ignored.